# Ruby - Combine two arrays by adding values

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays which each have a number of array elements. I want to add these two elements by using the first element of each array element as the identifier whereas adding the second element, e.g.:

```
a1= [ [0,1], [1,5], [7,3] ]
a2= [ [0,3], [3,2], [1,7] ]
```

As a result I want (note that the input arrays might not be sorted in any way):

```
[ [0,4], [1,12], [3,2], [7,3] ]
```

And the result should be sorted.

Comment: I cannot parse your sentences.

Comment: Please understand that not everyone is a native English speaker, hence my examples to show what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Of course not everyone is a native English speaker. That does not change the fact that I cannot parse your sentences.

Comment: For the record, Kumala, I could understand your requirements perfectly and the example provided made it as clear as could be.

Comment: I was able to grasp the meaning by looking at The Mini John's answer, not by reading the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it thusly:

```
(a + b).group_by(&:first).map { |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last).inject(:+)] }
```

First you put the arrays together with + since you don't care about a and b, you just care about their elements. Then the group_by partitions the combined array by the first element so that the inner arrays can easily be worked with. Then you just have to pull out the second (or last) elements of the inner arrays with v.map(&:last) and sum them with inject(:+).

For example:

```
>> a = [[1,10],[2,20],[3,30]]
>> b = [[1,50],[3,70]]
>> (a + b).group_by(&:first).map { |k,v| [k, v.map(&:last).inject(:+)] }
=> [[1, 60], [2, 20], [3, 100]]
```

Answer (score -2):

Relying on The Mini John's interpretation of the question:

```
(a1 + a2)
.inject([]) do |a, (i, n)|
  a.push([i, 0]) unless a.assoc(i)
  a.assoc(i)[1] += n
  a
end
.sort
# => [[0, 4], [1, 12], [3, 2], [7, 3]]
```

This does it in a single iteration.